# В каком месте запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Мой вечный камень преткновения. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каким месте тут должна быть запятая: "Он не будет работать даже если его починить". Запятая должна быть перед "даже" или перед "если"?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь запятая должна стоять перед словом "даже". Это придаточное условия, присоединяемое союзом "если", а даже - просто усилительная частица. Придаточное предложение вполне можно было записать так: "...если даже его починить". Тогда ведь у Вас никаких сомнений не было бы. Не правда ли?

Answer (score 0):

Иногда на месте запятой можно предположить точку. Если мысль понятна, значит, запятая нужа именно там. Сравните: "Он не будет работать". "Он не будет работать даже". Но это, наверное, только в этом контексте